# Why can't an app inside a docker container access it's own API endpoint?

Tags: node.js, docker, meteor, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I use the docker desktop app on Windows.
Inside a Ubuntu WSL2 I have a docker container with a meteor / nodejs server running.
Started via docker-compose from inside the WSL.

```
docker-compose.yaml
  ...
  environment:
    - ROOT_URL=http://localhost:8080
    - PORT=8080
  ports:
    - "8080:8080"
```

Call to Meteor-Files on the server, which will do the request:

```
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    UserFiles.load(url, options,
      (loadError, fileRef) => {
        if (loadError) {
          return reject(loadError);
        } else {
          return resolve(fileRef);
        }
      }, true);
  });
}
```

Now the app inside the docker container must access an HTTP endpoint of itself like `http://127.0.0.1:8080/api`

When I call the this endpoint from **outside** the docker, I get the correct result.

When I connect into the docker container with a terminal and curl the endpoint, I get the correct result.

**Update**: Also when running a Docker on a real Linux machine and not the WSL2 Ubuntu from Windows, it's working.

But, when the running app / service running inside the container tries to call itself by the same endpoint with the same URL, I get a `ECONNREFUSED - CONNECTION REFUSED` error.

Full Error Message:

```
FetchError: request to http://127.0.0.1:8080/api failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8080
at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/app/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/fetch/node_modules/node-fetch/lib/index.js:1444:11)
at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:315:20)
at ClientRequest.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12)
at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:426:9)
at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12)
at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
 => awaited here:
     at Function.Promise.await (/app/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/promise/node_modules/meteor-promise/promise_server.js:56:12)
     at imports/startup/filemigration.js:273:20
     at /app/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/promise/node_modules/meteor-promise/fiber_pool.js:43:40 {
   type: 'system',
   errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
   code: 'ECONNREFUSED'
 }
```

What could be the problem of this? Maybe a WSL2 security problem?

Comment: could you show the code you use inside your meteor app to call the endpoint? I assume this is server-side code, not client-side, right?

Comment: The code that tries to "access an HTTP endpoint of itself" is called "`startup/filemigration`", are you sure it runs after the server listens on the port? Typically within a `Meteor.startup()`? What if you try accessing much later?

Comment: @ghybs Well, I guess so. But I could try to execute the function later on just to be sure. Also I found out, that when I'm on a real Linux machine it seems to be working. So I'm still wondering if this is a security limitation of WSL Ubuntu.

Comment: @ChristianFritz Partly, I'm calling a "load" function from the meteor package "ostrio files" but it seems the call itself is done by the nodejs node-fetch module. I added the load call, and yes it's done on the server.

Comment: @ghybs Hey, your call was right. I delayed the call a bit and suddenly it worked. You can add the Answer, if you want. Also thx to all others who also helped solving the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error message, the code that ultimately needs to access an HTTP endpoint of the app itself, resides in a file called: `imports/startup/filemigration.js`

From its name, I assume it runs when the app starts. However, there is a possibility that the Meteor app has not started its `http` Node server yet, hence the "connection refused" error message.

There may even be a race condition between the different starting tasks, leading to different behaviors depending on the exact environments.

You can try delaying your startup / migration task a bit, if feasible, to ensure the Meteor app has correctly started its server and listens on the port.

You can typically use [`Meteor.startup(func)`](https://docs.meteor.com/api/core.html#Meteor-startup) for that:

> Run [func] code when a client or a server starts.
>
> [...]
>
> On a server, the function will run as soon as the server process is finished starting.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say anything for sure without looking at the actual code or seeing the full error message, but try to replace your

```
- ROOT_URL=http://localhost:8080
```

with

```
- ROOT_URL=http://127.0.0.1:8080
```

And if you have any other places with localhost url, replace them as well.

Comment: Hello i tried this as well with no luck. I added the error stack.

Comment: @Gobliins ok, I got it now. You can't access that resource because WSL has it's own localhost, which runs separatly from your main one. Here is an [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1690272) from a similar question which explains everything and sugests some solutions

Answer (score -1):

I also can't say anything certainly without looking at the code or error, but have you tried replacing the `localhost` with the name of the container within the compose file?